# Make a copy of certain columns from a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet file (master data) that I need to have its copy for my department. I want every change on master data is reflected to the copy file, including when someone adds a new tabsheet. Also, I just want to import certain columns from each tabsheet of master data to the copy file (column A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, N, O, AI, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, AO, AP, AQ).
Could someone please help enlighten me of what I did wrong?

Thank you.

I have tried using this code, but it doesn't work, and it slows down the copy sheet loading time.

```
function importData() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = 'Source ID';
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = 'Destination ID';
  var columnsToImport = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44];
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);

  for (var i = 0; i < sourceSheets.length; i++) {
    var sourceSheet = sourceSheets[i];
    var sourceSheetName = sourceSheet.getName();
    
    var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
    
    if (!destinationSheet) {
      destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.insertSheet(sourceSheetName);
    }
    
    destinationSheet.clear();

    var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = Math.max.apply(null, columnsToImport);
    
    if (lastRow > 0 && lastColumn > 0) {
      // Adjust lastColumn based on the columns to import
      var adjustedLastColumn = columnsToImport.indexOf(lastColumn) + 1;
      
      var dataRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, adjustedLastColumn);
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      
      var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, adjustedLastColumn);
      destinationRange.setValues(data);
    }
  }
}

function setTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('importData')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: lastColumn = columnsToImport,length

Answer (score 0):

Import just the columns you want:

I believe you were not calculating the number of columns correctly. Once I found that problem I stopped looking at your code and decided it's easier for me just to rewrite it.

```
function importData() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id);//global variable for ssid ...replace with appropriate strings
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test2id);//global variable for ssid ...replace with appropriate strings
  const idxs = ["A1","B1","C1","D1","E1","F1","G1","H1","I1","J1","N1","O1","AI1","AJ1","AK1","AL1","AM1","AN1","AO1","AP1","AQ1"].map(a1 => sss.getRange(a1).getColumn()-1);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(idxs));
  sss.getSheets().map((s => {
    let name = s.getName();
    let svs = s.getDataRange().getValues().map((r,i) => {
      return r.map((c,j) => ~idxs.indexOf(j) ? c : "~~~" ).filter(e => e != "~~~");//filter eliminates nulls from missing columns but leaves cells that other wise would evaluate to falsy
    });
    let dsh = dss.getSheetByName(name);
    if(!dsh) {
      dsh = dss.insertSheet(name);
    }
    dsh.clear();
    Logger.log(name);
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(svs));
    dsh.getRange(1,1,svs.length,svs[0].length).setValues(svs);
  }));
}
```

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)